# USB UDEV Rule Appears to Run Script Many Times

Tags: usb, scripts, udev, camera

I wrote a custom udev rule that looks for a specific usb device to be plugged in, and then runs a few gphoto commands. See below:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04a9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="32a1", RUN+="/usr/bin/gphoto2 --set-config /main/settings/capturetarget=1 && /usr/bin/gphoto2 --capture-image --interval 5"
```

Essentially, this should allow for my connected camera to set the storage method to the camnera's SD card, then take photos every 5 seconds for an infinite number of shots (or until I unplug the camera). However, the application seems to be running multiple instances of itself (may be something else going on, though). After taking a few photos (5 - 15) the camera stops taking shots.

However, when I run these exact commands as a local user (i.e. user:pi on a raspberry pi) the camera functions as I would expect.

Any help is greatly appreciated, as I am fairly new to udev rules and don't understand why this isn't working.

Comment: Did you by any chance get this problem resolved? Can you guide what you found out? Thanks!

Comment: Update from my last comment: I still have not gotten this to work. I abandoned the project a little while ago as it was eating up too much time. I know other people have gotten similar things to work, but just can't fathom why my commands and script work just fine when run directly from the user shell but start to act really odd when udev is involved.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your recipe is that you use shell syntax, namely the structure  command1 && command2. But udev does not pass the command to a shell, so shell constructs such as job control and IO redirection are NOT available.

You can use something like

RUN+="sh -c 'some commands here but you cannot use double-quotes'"

Anyway, I landed at this question because I also have the problem that the udev rules for my keyboard fires something like 6 times when I switch KVM.

Comment: any `RUN` commands block the udev daemon until they finish; they will be killed if they take too long.  better to create a script (`/usr/local/bin/myCameraInit.sh`), place in it any commands you want to run, and have the udev rule `RUN+="/usr/local/bin/myCameraInit.sh"`.  see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/56243/222377 & http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28711/222377